# OpenGL transformation around arbitrary anchor point

Tags: math, opengl, 3d

I am using programmable pipeline (OpenGL 4).The problem is as follows.I have default primitive called "plane" which has 4 vertices -defined in clip space coordnates [ -1 , 1] range.
I never move those directly to scale the plane but apply scale to the model matrix instead.
So for example , to get a plane with width =100,height=50 I scale the plane:

```
_modelMatrix.scale(100/2,50/2,1);
```

Also I have an anchor point which defines the center of the plane and which can be moved around to offset the local center.
THE PROBLEM:
It all works fine till I start scaling the plane after moving the pivot.So for example, if the plane width=100 and height=100 ,and I want to offset the center  to be at the left top corner of the plane I translate the model matrix to current position + adding x and y offset values (50 and -50).I get the center to be there all right.But then, when I scale the plane again the pivot center is not kept relative to the new scale but gets shift as it doesn't scale along with the object.What is the right way to make sure the defined anchor gets adjusted relative to a new scale?I know that in the fixed pipeline it is solved easily by adding anchor offset to the vertices directly when defining them via API calls , but in my case I don't recreate the vertex buffer on each render loop and don't want to as I must keep default vertex number range for some stuff I do in Shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [standard order-of-transforms problem](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Positioning/Tut06%20Fun%20with%20Matrices.html). The solution is to apply the transformations *in the correct order*. If you want to scale then offset, then do it that way. If you want to offset then scale relative to the new offset, do it that way. Neither is "correct"; it all depends on what you want.

For your case, you need to apply the scale first, before the translation. Assuming that you're right-multiplying with column-major matrices, that means you supply the scale *last*.